# How to check if foreigh key violation will be triggered before executing SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Before I execute SQL query, I'd like to check if foreign key constraint will be violated. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not simply execute the statement and deal with the error message? Much more efficient if in most of the cases, you don't expect an error.

Comment: I don't like it because it is reported as error, and it should just be a warning to the user. It's too radical and confuses the user as it was something really problematic while it's not.

Comment: Well, then just report it as a warning. It's completely up to you how you deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the foreign key's existence with a SELECT statement. To do that in a completely transparent way, you'd need to write code that examines either system tables or information_schema views, builds the right SELECT statement on the fly, then executes it and examines the result. You can hardcode most of that stuff, but only at the risk of executing code that's based on assumptions that no longer exist. (FKs might be dropped, tables renamed, etc.)

But there are some problems with both those approaches.

- You have to put that SELECT statement (or statements) *and* the INSERT or UPDATE statement within a single transaction. Otherwise, you risk verifying the existence of a value that someone else deletes before your update.  In other words, your SELECT succeeds, someone else's DELETE (or UPDATE) succeeds, your INSERT (or UPDATE) *should* succeed, but fails because of bad transaction handling.
- The server has to process two queries for every INSERT or UPDATE statement. (And that doesn't count queries against the system tables.)
- You still have to trap errors at the application level anyway. There are a *lot* of things that can prevent a sensible transaction from committing.

Since you have to trap errors anyway, it usually makes more sense to just issue the INSERT or UPDATE statement, and trap the error that says you violated a foreign key constraint.